# Fix youtube embed position

Tags: html, css, embed

I added an embed video to my website but it has a really bad position, how do I fix it?

This is how it looks like now: [image]

This is how I want it to look like (Red box is embed video): [image]

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  
}

.container {
  min-height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column; 
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 23px;
  border-style: solid;
  text-shadow: #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px, #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px, #000 0px 0px 1px, #000 0px 0px 1px;
  margin-top: 215px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
.menu{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.aboutp{
    width: 1000px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
}
.mario{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 20vw;
    margin: auto;
}
.topContent{
    background-color: red;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 70vw;
    max-width: 700px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1.5vh;
    border-style: solid;
}
.mainContent{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 50px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-size: 1.5vh;
    max-width: 768px;

}

.left {
    width:15%;
    float: left;
}

.right{
    width:15%;
}

.center {
    width:65%;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-style: solid;
}

.bottom {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 768px;
    max-height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    border-style: solid;
}

.bottom a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 2vh;
    width: 768px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2vh;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    text-shadow: #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px, #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px, #000 0px 0px 1px, #000 0px 0px 1px;

}
```

```html
<div class = "topContent">
        <h1>Game History</h1>
    </div>
<div class = "mainContent">
        <div class="left">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JO86YAiYFjc" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <p class="aboutp1">
                 bunch of text
            </p>
            <p class="aboutp2"> 
                      bunch of text
                <img src="../resources/mario-super.gif" alt="Mario Gif" class="mariogif">
                      bunch of text
            </p>

            <p class="aboutp3">
                  bunch of text
                         </p>
            <p class="aboutp4">      
                            bunch of text
                            </p>
            <p class="aboutp5">
                  bunch of text
                                 </p>
                
        </div>
        <div class="right"><img src="../resources/mario.png" alt="Mario Image" class="mario"></div>

    
    <div class="bottom">
        </div>
    
</div>
```

As you can see the image is both behind the text and has a bad position. I think this might be because I put it in "mainContent" which has a max-width of 768px, but I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What Layout do you want to achieve on mobile devices where the video won't fit side to side with the main content? Where should the Video and the Mario Image be on small screens?

Comment: @Laisender That doesn't really matter in my case since I'm only making it to be on PC but I guess I would like them to be on the bottom